# Is chi square the best approach for looking at number of cases by year

Tags: chi-squared-test, independence

I have the number of people diagnosed with a condition in each quintile of deprivation over five different years. We are interested in whether numbers of diagnoses are going up faster in more deprived quintiles. The data looks like this:

[image]

It looks to me very much like it rises much faster in the more deprived quintiles, on the left (Q1 and Q2).

I thought chi square was the best approach but:

```
test = structure(list(Q1 = c(98L, 109L, 263L, 323L, 312L),
                      Q2 = c(90L, 113L, 199L, 237L, 247L),
                      Q3 = c(70L, 83L, 133L, 166L, 182L), 
               Q4 = c(20L, 39L, 60L, 87L, 90L),
                      Q5 = c(38L, 50L, 75L, 101L, 115L)),
                 .Names = c("Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4", "Q5"),
                 class = "data.frame", row.names =
                   c("2008/09", "2009/10", "2010/11", "2011/12", "2012/13"))

chisq.test(test)

    Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  test
X-squared = 17.285, df = 16, p-value = 0.3674
```

The thing that I can see is missing is that the years are really ordered, we are looking at an increase, but of course the chi-square just treats them as nominal.

I don't think I can use logistic regression because I'm just looking at a caseload- I don't have loads of people who don't have the disorder to compare with, just the increase over time.

Or is it the right approach and it really just isn't significant?

Thanks.

Comment: *Both* variables are ordered. An ordinary chi-square will potentially be throwing away a lot of power, though it depends on the exact hypotheses you're most interested in.

Comment: Of course! They are both ordered. Is there such a thing as an ordered chi square? I never heard of such a thing

Comment: There are actually several possible ways to analyze such data, some of which would correspond to some form of chi-square. However, with this data, I'd probably be looking at modelling it as something like a cumulative logit model on the quantile groups with time as a independent variable. It kind of depends on what kinds of things you want to test.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say regular ordinary least square regression should be fine, although technically, your dependent variable is a count, so you should use Poisson or negative binomial regression.  But with counts this high, I would guess that OLS regression would give similar results